# css footer menu display:table and items not balanced

Tags: css, width, display

Hi i am trying to write a footer which should have balanced width items because of their width.

In my example , if the sentence is long, it s seems that there is a more large padding. "Blog" has a little padding, "First column very long" has a large one.

Thx for the help.

```
<div class=footer>
<UL>
<LI>First column very long</LI>
<LI>Contact us</LI>
<LI>Blog</LI>
<LI>Privacy policy very large title</LI>
<LI>why?</LI>
<LI>The last sentence</LI>
</UL>
</div>


.footer{
width:100%;
 border: 1px solid yellow;
 }
 .footer ul
{
 list-style-type:none;
display:table;
width:100%;
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
padding:0;
}

.footer ul li
{
 display:table-cell;
text-align:center;
border:1px solid red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rtjposu9/

Answer (score 2):

This is a very normal phenomenon. If you wish to balance the widths of the elements,  use width in percentage to help you, for example `width:16.66%;`

However, since that will instead cause another problem of words overflowing, you should also use `overflow:hidden` and `word-wrap:break-word`